# how do I request information before starting to use the spreadsheet, such as a date range

Tags: google-apps-script

I need request information before start to use my spreadsheet it is a date range, if you dont enter the date range the spreadsheet must be closed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an `onOpen()` function that would trigger the opening of a dialog and have the dialog remain open as long as the user does not enter the date range you want. I don't think you could force the closing of the spreadsheet if no value is entered though.

Comment: I know onOpen function is to add a  option the  prinicpal menu but you could give me an idea of ​​the script to use in this case please thank you very much

Comment: Actually, onOpen() can be used for anything that needs to be triggered when the spreadsheet is being open. Therefore, you can include there any code you want to create a UI element using the Ui Service (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_ui), with either PopupPanel or DialogBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a UI using UiApp, it would show a link to your spreadsheet only if a condition is validated,else it would reject the request.

**EDIT :** Here is an example to let you start with :

(the condition has to be defined, I commented the part that must be completed by you...

```
 function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setStyleAttribute('padding', '15').setStyleAttribute('background', 'beige').setWidth('300').setHeight('140');// adjust dimensions to your needs  

  var mygrid = app.createGrid(3, 2);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('StartDate:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createDateBox().setId('dateA'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('EndDtate:'));
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createDateBox().setId('dateB'));

  var mybutton = app.createButton('OK');
  mybutton.setId("mybutton");
  var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  mypanel.setId('mypanel');
  mypanel.add(mygrid);
  var label = app.createHTML('<BR>Your request has been approved, <BR><BR>thanks for submitting').setId('Label').setStyleAttribute('padding', '15').setVisible(false).setWidth('300').setHeight('120');// adjust dimensions to your needs  
  var anchor = app.createAnchor('Open the Spreadsheet', 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dDljeXhtY3lacUtxdllQbGNHREY0VUE#gid=0').setId('anchor').setVisible(false)
  mypanel.add(label).add(anchor)
  mypanel.add(mybutton);
  app.add(mypanel).add(label);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('checkDates');
  handler.addCallbackElement(mypanel);
  mybutton.addClickHandler(handler);
   var Chandler = app.createClientHandler();
   Chandler.forTargets(mygrid,mybutton).setVisible(false)
   mybutton.addClickHandler(Chandler)     
  return app;
}

function checkDates(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var Label = app.getElementById('Label');
  var anchor = app.getElementById('anchor');
  Label.setVisible(true);// show the masking label with message
  var dateA = e.parameter.dateA;
  var dateB = e.parameter.dateB;
// write your condition...  
//  if(dateA)...&& dateB== ...
  anchor.setVisible(true);
  return app
// }else{
app.close
//return app}
}
```

Comment: Thanks please can you give an idea?

Comment: i am waiting for the script tahn ks for your help a lot

Comment: Yes I know... too busy but didn't forget... I'll  try to finish it tomorrow morning...